# Line spacing applied to wrong row of tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, line-spacing, multicolumn

I observed very strange spacing problems in a `tabular` seemingly caused by the `array` package.
Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\[15pt]
 a \\
 a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:

[image: with array]

But clearly, the increased line-spacing of `15pt` has been applied to the wrong row.
I have tried to strip the example down further, but apparently the `multicolumn` is required for this strange effect.

The output I originally intended can be obtain when we avoid using the `array` package. It looks like this:

[image: without array]

**Questions**

- Is the observed behavior intended or a bug?
- Assuming it is intended: 
  I must be doing something wrong.
  How can I obtain the expected output while `array` is used?
- Assuming it's a bug:
  Is it known? Can I avoid it somehow?

Comment: I get the expected result when I compile your minimal example.

Comment: I do not have this problem with you code. Just in case: are all the packages up-to-date?

Comment: yes, packages up to date. But I'm on a rolling release, maybe something is temporarily broken.

Comment: As a work-around, try `\\ \noalign{\vspace*{15pt}}`

Comment: That works around the issue. Can you explain, why? Also, will it work with older tex-versions as well?

Comment: @m8mble from the github issue you added it appears that you have 2.4g, but on CTAN there 2.4h so it is not current.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Thanks for your help and sorry for the dupe. I assumed my rolling release distro would be more up to date.

Comment: @m8mble this is why we always require a .log file in a bug report ... it just happens too often :-).  Maybe checkmark the answer below if you get your problem resolved after updating.

Comment: Sure. I’ll wait with that, until I can confirm it is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug that got introduced a while back and corrected early May 2018 (version v2.4i or h of array). Distributions should have it included (DVD's obviously not), so if necessary run package update on your distribution.

Comment: I can confirm that array v2.4h does not contain this bug. Thanks for your help.